# Using jQuery hover over a link

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add a simple jQuery slidedown function for upon hovering.I can get the slidedown to work when I attach the action to the body of the document, but when the image I use as a link is attached, it does not work. Here it is setup for the div

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
jQuery('.desTitle').hide()
});
jQuery('#desGal').hover(function()
{
jQuery('.desTitle').slideDown('slow');
});
```

The HTML is:

```
<div id="contain">
<div class="desTitle"><a href="link"><img src="imgTitle"></a></div>
<div id="desGal"><a href="link"><img src="img"></a></div>
</div>
```

I believe the link is the issue, but am unsure. Is it possible to create a jQuery hover event on a link?

Comment: You forgot to close your <img src="img"> tag

Comment: Sorry, it is closed in my code, just removed path, and forgot to close here.

Comment: Self closing tags are unnecessary in HTML5 IIRC

Comment: Seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cWJyJ/

Comment: You probably have a z-index issue where something else is on top of the img blocking the click/hover. Can you select it with firebug etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the hover event registration inside the `document.ready`. It could be possible that the event registry happens before the element `#desGal` exists/document is loaded.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.desTitle').hide();

   jQuery('#desGal').hover(function () {
    jQuery('.desTitle').slideDown('slow');
});
});
```

Did you mean to toggle the slide then use `slideToggle()`

Comment: Yup, for some reason putting the function outside `document.ready` was the issue.

Comment: Yes seemed like so. Because in your live page you probably might be loading your scripts first and takes sometime to load the elements than the script, hence this could have caused the issue.

Comment: With `slideToggle()` it re-fires during hover, I could do a function for `mouseover()` and `mouseout()`, but that seems to defeat the purpose, because I could just do a function for a `slideDown()` and `slideUp()` Can I make it fire once on hover?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following CSS to hide the original picture to be shown on `hover`:

### CSS

```
.desTitle {
    display:none;
}
```

And then added teh following JavaScript code, also managing the out event of the hover:

### JavaScript/jQuery

```
jQuery('#desGal').hover(function () {
    jQuery('.desTitle').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zS2sC/)

Comment: would it not be simpler to do this? `$('#desGal').hover(function(){ $('.desTitle').slideToggle(); });`

Comment: @Connor Yes, it would. I thought *PSL* was about to add it to its code in his answer at the time of posting, so I wanted to post an alternative. I might edit this though.

Comment: You should't make your answers worse just because someone has the same part of code as you, after all you have to write the same code as everyone else to build stuff.